# Improving Diophantine approximation by rescaling

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation, continued-fractions

Let $\lambda\in(0,1)$ be an irrational number such that its continued fraction expansion is bounded (for example, an irrational quadratic number, whose continued fraction is periodic). It is known that the bound
$$\left|\lambda-\frac{p}{q}\right|\leq \frac{C}{q^2},$$
where $\frac{p}{q}$ is a convergent (best rational approximation) of $\lambda$, is optimal for some positive constant $C$, namely
$$\mathop{\liminf_{p,q\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}}}_{(p,q)=1}\,q |q\lambda-p|>0.$$
Consider now pairs of the form $(\theta,\theta\lambda)$, with $\theta>0$. I would like to understand whether there is a choice of $\theta$ such that $(\theta,\theta\lambda)$ is *simultaneously* approximabile by rationals with a slightly better bound than $1/q^2$. More precisely, my question is:

**does there exists $\theta>0$ such that**
$$\mathop{\liminf_{p_1,p_2,q\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}}}_{(p_1,q)=(p_2,q)=1}\,\max\{q |q\theta-p_1|,q |q\theta\lambda-p_2|\}=0$$
**holds true?**

Equivalently, we are asking the following. Let
$$W:=\big\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^+\,\mbox{such that}\mathop{\liminf_{p_1,p_2,q\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}}}_{(p_1,q)=(p_2,q)=1}\,\max_{i=1,2} q |qx_i-p_i|=0\big\},$$
which is a fractal set with Hausdorff dimension $\frac32$. Is it true that $W$ intersects the line passing through $(0,0)$ and $(1,\lambda)$?

A natural candidate for $\theta$ could be a Liouville number, since Liouville numbers have good properties of simultaneous approximation with other irrationals.

It would be already interesting to prove that such a choice of $\theta$ exists for some specific $\lambda$ with bounded continued fraction.

Comment: I believe this is true， depending on whether we can find a number with good continued fraction expansion on the trajectory of rescaling.

Comment: I agree, still it is unclear to me how to find a pair in the rescaling trajectory which has simultaneous good approximation. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I think it is hard to imagine how the continued fraction expansion varies on the trajectory,  maybe a good understanding of the gauss map $G(x)=\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}=\frac{1}{x}-\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor$ will help imagine it, I may not be able to make constructive suggestions because I haven't thought about it before.